# Is there an historical connection between Hinduism and Christianity?

Tags: history, tradition, other-religions

I have grown up as a christian (catholic). Yesterday, I visited a Hindu temple and can't help but notice some similarities

- Praying people either put their flat hands together or fold them together, intertwisting fingers
- "Mariamman" is worshipped as a 'mother' goddess ... similarly, in cristianity, "Maria", the mother of Jesus, is often also worshipped on her own and although not a true goddess, sometimes treated as such in places like Lourdes
- People would decorate their forehead with ashes. In cristian tradition, people would put a cross out of ashes on their forehead on [Ash Wednesday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_Wednesday) .

I know that Christianity is much younger and descendent from Judaism. But are all of these similarities pure coincidence?

Comment: very unlikely to be just a coincidence. all world religions are copies of Sanatan Dharma in some diluted form or other. the highest spiritual concept "surrender" in Christianity is etymologically connected to Sanskrit word 'Sharan', just as that "namaz" in Islam is to Namah in Sanskrit. There is also a legend about the missing 12 years of Jesus's life (from 21-33) probably spent in Himalayas doing tapasya or learning under yogis. The concept of virgin birth exists (ayonija) in Hindu historical accounts since at least 5000 years ago.

Comment: the concept of baptism/born again is derived from Dvija (2 births for those who have undergone initiation of scriptures), staying virgin until marriage and giving-away of daughter to groom, is copied from kanya-daan (virgin-donation) etc. Conservatives of all religions speak similar language. It is my opinion that the major religions are for people of different characteristics - those who are Satvik are drawn to Hinduism, those who are Rajasik drawn to Christianity, and Tamasik are drawn to Islam, and as you progress spiritually, you get 'promoted' to higher religions over multiple births.

Comment: This question is more relevant to History SE under the  tag history of religions.Voting to close as off topic. - https://history.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BTW its Mari Amman (Amman means mother) and not Maria mman.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar the help center mentions "Questions about Hindu practices" and "Historical questions about the evolution of Hinduism" as on-topic and the off-topic examples seem much more remote

Comment: @Wouter - This question isn't about either history or evolution of Hinduism instead it asks for historical connection about Hinduism and  Christianity. There is already a stack exchange site for such historical questions and best suited for it. Apart from that this question is also broad , there are many similarities which although seems common but are not absolutely connected. As the above comment mentions Hinduism or Sanatan Dharma is far older.

Comment: @mar I like your analysis,but I’d like to add that even among these “Rajasik/tamasik “ faiths(as you call them),people who have progressed to higher levels of spirituality believe in the universal validity of all faiths(including Sanatan Dharm)(although they may prefer not to make statements in this regard as it may be cause chaos,especially Ina country like India),something that **a fraction of** bigoted Abrahamaic people refuse to accept.

Comment: @Amethyst - that fraction is more than 0.9